# why font list is empty for imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, fonts, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to add some text to an image. But I found it always said that my specified font doesn't exist. After reading the manual carefully I noticed that I can use `convert -list font` to output all the available fonts, but after trying I figured out that the list of available font is empty.

This is what I get:

```
shell$ convert -list font
shell$
```

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: Which IM version are you on?

Comment: Latest from the official site.  `ImageMagick-6.8.9`

Comment: Maybe have a look here http://martin-thoma.com/add-a-new-font-to-imagemagick/

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, but I can't even go through the first line. `sudo updatedb` returns `updatedb: command not found`.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 63):

I just managed to tell **ImageMagick** about the fonts on my OSX system like this:

```
# Make a new directory for ImageMagick local settings and cd into it
mkdir ~/.magick
cd ~/.magick

# Grab script to find all fonts on system and store them in a config file
curl -L http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen > type_gen

# Run script, telling it where my fonts are and create "type.xml" file with list  
find /System/Library/Fonts /Library/Fonts ~/Library/Fonts -name "*.[to]tf" | perl type_gen -f - > type.xml

# Go to ImageMagick config folder - see note at end to find correct folder
cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/etc/ImageMagick-6

# Edit system config file called "type.xml" and add line near end to tell IM to look at local file we made in earlier step
<typemap>
<include file="type-ghostscript.xml" />
<include file="~/.magick/type.xml" />                       ### THIS LINE ADDED ### 
</typemap>
```

### How to find the correct folder for your `type.xml` file

The folder where `type.xml` is stored can vary enormously between systems and versions. Most recently the user configuration folder seems to be `~/.config/ImageMagick`, but the best way I know of finding it is to run the following command to see where **ImageMagick** is looking:

```
convert -debug configure -list font 2>&1 | grep -E "Searching|Loading"

Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/share/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/lib/ImageMagick//config-Q16HDRI/type.xml"
Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
Searching for configure file: "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml"
Searching for configure file: "/Users/username/.config/ImageMagick/type.xml"
Loading type configure file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml" ...
Loading type configure file "/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.11-6/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-ghostscript.xml" ...
Loading type configure file "/Users/username/.config/ImageMagick/type.xml" ...
```

So there are lots of places you could insert the fonts. In general, if you choose a folder starting with `/etc` or `/usr/local` the fonts will be available for all users and for scripts in your web server to use - if you want that. On the other hand, if you are just a single user, you may prefer to keep the font config file in your login directory, e.g. `~/.config/ImageMagick/type.xml`.

Comment: Thanks. I got stuck at this `# Go to ImageMagick config folder`. I don't have a `/usr/local/Cellar/` in my harddrive.

Comment: I finally managed to locate the `etc` folder in the package folder. But after running the `convert` command, I got this: `convert: delegate library support not built-in '/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1535.`

Just fyi, I now can see things after running `convert -list font`

Comment: Mmmmm... if you don't have a /usr/local/Cellar, then I suspect you are not using the `homebrew` package manager that I use. I have never succeeded in making ImageMagick work without using that and I use it for installing everything from `sed`, through `date` through `awk`, `lynx`, `netcat`, `wget`, `jhead`, `parallel`, `redis`. I am not sure I can help much further if you don't use homebrew. Maybe hunt around your Mac for a `type.xml` file, save it, and replace it with the one we created in my answer and see if that helps. Sorry, I don't know much more.

Comment: Thanks. I have already found an post here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21070 but unluckily even if I generated a `type.xml` file it still doesn't work. The XML file looks like this:
`<type format="otf" name="YuppySC" glyphs="/Library/Fonts/YuppySC-Regular.otf" />` Is it correct?

And in the post people are talking about using `convert -list configure` but when I run it I got this: `convert: unable to access configure file 'configure.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/706`.

Comment: another question, what is `type-ghostscript.xml` for? thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it works! You are looking for .ttf only though and imagemagick supports .otf too (for Chinese,Japanese and Korean). The command should be: find /System/Library/Fonts /Library/Fonts ~/Library/Fonts -name "*.ttf" -or -name "*.otf" | perl type_gen -f - > type.xml

Comment: @kexik Thank you for your feedback, I will change my post to incorporate ".otf" fonts too.

Comment: Thanks! I created my `type.xml` in `~/.config/ImageMagick` and it was detected automatically!

Comment: If you install imagemagick with homebrew, use: `brew install imagemagick --with-little-cms`. After this the instructions worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I installed my image magick magic with homebrew, and it had all of the system fonts. However, `convert -list fonts` showed that it only looked in /etc/Image-Magick.../type-apple.xml and not in type.xml (where we add the created file to the typemap). I had to manually copy and paste the new type.xml into type-apple.xml to get it to work. Super smelly.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions, this worked great for me.

Comment: Works great, but I had to set the absolute path 

Not Working
<include file="~/.magick/type.xml" />                       ### THIS LINE ADDED ### 

Working
<include file="/Users/mark/.magick/type.xml" />                       ### THIS LINE ADDED ### 

with ImageMagick 7.0.9-5

Answer (score 10):

With ImageMagic 7.0.10 on MacOs Catalina I have done the following which did the trick.

- Edited `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-7/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml` and replaced `type-ghostscript` with `type-apple`
- Edited `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-7/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-apple.xml` and added "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental" in front of all glyph paths