# Font not rendering properly using imagemagick converting from svg to png

Tags: macos, shell, svg, imagemagick, png

I've tried my best troubleshooting and I'm still coming up short. Basically, just trying to convert a svg to png and the font is not rendering. I have the font installed on my machine; I've added all the fonts I have on my machine to a 'type.xml' document like some have said. I updated my imagemagick to use rsvg instead of msvg too.

Here's the command I'm using:
    $ /usr/local/bin/rsvg-convert ~/desktop/example.svg -o ~/desktop/example.png

I attached the svg code along with the my current png.[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<path d="M242.3,171.9c0.1,2.1,0.6,3.9,1.2,5.5c3.9,0.7,8.8-1.4,12.6,0.2c0.9-2.6,1.1-5.9,1.2-8.9c0.1-1.7,0.2-3.4,0.4-4.6
 c0.6-3.7,1.1-7.1,0.2-9.8c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8,0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7,0.3c-0.9,0.3-1.7,0.8-2.7,0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.5
 c-1.3,0-2.5,0-3.7,0c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0.2
 c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.2c-0.5-0.4-1.1,0-1.5-0.4c-0.7,0.1-1.4-0.4-2.2-0.4c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0C241.7,159.5,241.9,166.4,242.3,171.9z
 "/>
<g>
 <path d="M242.1,153.8c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.8c-0.8-0.4-1.5-1.2-1.7-2.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4
  c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.7-0.6-1.1c-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.3-1.2c-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-1-0.8c-0.9-0.6-1.6-1.3-2.5-1.8c-1.2-0.8-2.4-1.7-3.7-2.4
  c-1.5-0.8-2.9-1.6-4.4-2.3c-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.7c-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.4-1.8-0.7c-1.3-0.6-2.6-1-3.9-1.5c-1.2-0.5-2.5-0.9-3.7-1.4
  c-1.2-0.5-2.5-0.9-3.7-1.4c-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3.7-1.3c-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.6-2.1-0.7c-0.7-0.2-1.5-0.5-2.2-0.7c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.8
  c-0.8-0.3-1.6-0.5-2.4-0.8c-1-0.4-2-0.7-3.1-1c-0.8-0.3-1.5-0.6-2.3-0.8c-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.4-1.7-0.6c-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.3-1.7-0.5
  c-0.6-0.3-1.3-0.5-1.9-0.6c-1.6-0.3-3.1-0.9-4.6-1.3c-1.2-0.3-2.3-0.9-3.5-1.3c-0.9-0.3-1.7-0.9-2.8-0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.4,0.7
  c0,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.4,1c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.6c-0.2,1-0.7,1.9-1,2.9c-0.3,1.1-0.8,2.2-1.1,3.3c-0.4,1.3-0.7,2.6-1.2,3.8
  c-0.7,1.8-1.1,3.8-1.8,5.6c-0.3,0.9-0.6,1.7-0.9,2.6c-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.6-0.6,2.5c-0.1,0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.5c-0.3,1,0,1.9-0.2,2.8
  c0.3,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.4c0,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.4c0.1,0.8,0,1.6,0.2,2.4c0.1,0.7,0,1.5,0.2,2.3c0.2,0.9,0,1.9,0.2,2.8
  c0.2,0.8,0,1.5,0.2,2.3c0.2,0.6,0,1.3,0,1.9c0,0.6,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.9c0.1,1,0.1,2.1,0.2,3.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1
  c0.3,0.5,0.1,1.1,0.2,1.7c0,0.6,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.7c-0.1,1.1,0.1,2.3-0.2,3.4v12.6c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2c0.3,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.3
  c0.1,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.4c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0.5,1.4,0.5,2.8,1.1,4.2c-0.1,0.8,0.4,1.4,0.6,2.1c0.2,0.7,0.5,1.4,0.7,2
  c0.9,2.2,2,4.3,3,6.5c0.3,0.5,0.5,1.1,0.8,1.6c0.5,0.9,1,1.9,1.4,2.8c0.4,0.8,0.7,1.7,1.4,2.3c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9-0.3
  c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c1.2-0.7,2.6-1.2,3.9-1.7c1.4-0.6,2.8-1.2,4.2-1.8c1.4-0.6,2.9-1.2,4.3-1.8c1.2-0.6,2.5-1.1,3.7-1.7
  c1.7-0.7,3.2-1.6,4.9-2.3c0.8-0.4,1.6-0.8,2.4-1.2c1.3-0.5,2.4-1.2,3.6-1.9c1.2-0.7,2.5-1.3,3.7-2c1.2-0.7,2.5-1.3,3.7-2
  c1.3-0.8,2.7-1.5,4-2.3c1.1-0.6,2.2-1.3,3.3-2c0.6-0.4,1.4-0.7,2-1.2c1.4-1.1,2.9-2,4.3-3.2c1.2-1,2.4-1.9,3.6-3c1-1,2.1-2,3.1-3
  c1.4-1.4,2.8-2.9,4.2-4.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.7h0.8c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.4-0.6c-0.6-1.7-1-3.4-1.1-5.5
  C241,166.4,240.8,159.4,242.1,153.8z"/>
 <path d="M331.1,160.8c0-1.7,0.2-3.4-0.1-5.1c-0.1-0.6,0.1-1.3-0.2-2c0.1-1.1-0.3-2.2-0.4-3.3c0-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.6
  c0-0.3,0.1-0.6,0-0.8c-0.2-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.4-1.8c-0.2-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.4-1.8c-0.2-0.6-0.4-1.3-0.4-2c-0.5-1-0.6-2.2-0.9-3.3
  c-0.3-1.3-0.7-2.5-1-3.8c-0.3-1.2-0.8-2.4-1.1-3.6c-0.7-2.1-1.5-4.1-2.3-6.2c-0.6-1.7-1.4-3.3-1.6-5.1c0-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6
  c-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.8-0.9c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.2c-0.8,0.2-1.7,0.4-2.5,0.7c-1.2,0.4-2.3,0.8-3.5,1.3c-1.1,0.4-2.1,0.9-3.2,1.3
  c-1.1,0.4-2.1,0.9-3.2,1.2c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.5-2.6,0.7c-0.6,0.2-1.3,0.3-1.9,0.6c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.6-2.7,0.8c-1.5,0.4-3,1-4.5,1.4
  c-0.9,0.3-1.8,0.6-2.7,1c-0.9,0.3-1.7,0.6-2.6,1c-1.2,0.5-2.4,1-3.6,1.5c-1,0.4-2,0.9-3,1.4c-1.3,0.7-2.6,1.5-3.9,2.2
  c-0.6,0.4-1.3,0.8-1.9,1.2c-1,0.7-2.1,1.5-3.1,2.2c-1,0.7-1.9,1.6-2.9,2.3c-0.4,0.3-0.9,0.7-1.3,1c-0.6,0.5-1.1,1-1.7,1.5
  c-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.7-1.1,1c-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.8-1.6,1.2c-1,0.9-2.1,1.7-3.2,2.5c-0.7,0.6-1.5,1.3-2.2,1.9c-0.5,0.5-0.9,1.1-1.4,1.6
  c-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.1,1.3c0,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.1,1c0.9,3,0.4,6.6-0.2,10.2c-0.2,1.2-0.3,2.9-0.3,4.5c-0.2,3.1-0.4,6.5-1.3,9.2
  c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0.1c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.7,1.2,1.1
  c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.7,1.2,1.1c1.1,1.1,2.2,2.2,3.2,3.3c1,1,2,2.1,3,3.1c0.9,0.8,1.8,1.6,2.7,2.3c0.6,0.5,1.2,0.9,1.7,1.4
  c1.6,1.2,3.2,2.3,4.8,3.4c1.2,0.8,2.5,1.6,3.8,2.4c1.3,0.7,2.6,1.4,3.8,2.1c1.1,0.6,2.2,1,3.2,1.6c0.5,0.3,1.1,0.5,1.7,0.8
  c0.7,0.3,1.4,0.7,2.2,1c0.8,0.3,1.4,0.7,2.2,1c0.7,0.3,1.5,0.6,2.2,1c0.7,0.4,1.4,0.6,2.1,0.9c0.7,0.3,1.4,0.7,2.2,1
  c1,0.4,1.9,0.7,2.8,1.2c1.1,0.5,2.3,0.8,3.3,1.5c0.5-0.1,0.8,0.3,1.2,0.5c1,0.3,2,0.8,3,1.2c0.9,0.4,1.9,0.8,2.8,1.2
  c1.1,0.5,2.1,0.8,3.1,1.4c0.5,0.3,1,0.5,1.5,0.7c0.7-0.2,1.1-0.7,1.2-1.4c0-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.8-1.7,1.6-3.4,2.4-5.1
  c0.7-1.5,1.4-3,2-4.6l0.8-2c0.6-1.6,1.2-3.2,1.7-4.8c0.3-0.9,0.7-1.8,0.8-2.7c0.2-1,0.5-1.9,0.6-2.8c0.2-1.2,0.6-2.4,0.9-3.6
  c0.1-0.5,0-1.1,0.2-1.4c0.2-0.5,0-1,0.3-1.4c0.2-1.7,0.9-3.2,0.9-4.8c0.4-0.3,0.1-0.8,0.3-1.2c0.2-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.3
  c0.1-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.3c0.1-2-0.1-4,0.2-5.9c0.2-1.1,0.1-2.3,0.2-3.5C331.3,164.3,331.2,162.5,331.1,160.8z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M247.5,337.9c7.6,3.2,16.2,4.9,25.4,4.9c26.5,0,48.7-15.2,48.7-30.6c0-11.1-15.1-12.9-24.3-12.9
 c-19.9,0-41.8,9.3-60.5,21.3c0.2,2.5,0.2,5.2,0.2,7.7c0,32-15.9,51.7-37.1,51.7c-5.1,0-11.3-2.4-11.3-8.7
 c0-12.3,20.2-35.1,46.6-52.1c-0.5-6.6-1.4-13.1-2.5-19.8c-15.9,15-28.2,33.6-41.6,33.6c-4.8,0-10-2.1-10-8.1
 c0-13.5,19-25.9,32.5-33.9c5-2.9,10.9-6.3,16.7-10.2c-0.4-4.2-0.6-8.5-0.6-13c0-24.1,11.4-54.3,30.3-54.3c7.8,0,10.9,7.3,10.9,14.9
 c0,21.5-18.6,38.8-37.6,51.8c0.1,3.9,0.3,7.5,0.6,11.2c9.7-7.1,21.1-12.4,34.9-12.4c2.2,0,4.4,0.2,6.7,0.5l-0.3,1.6
 c-1.4-0.2-2.7-0.2-4.1-0.2c-14.6,0-26.3,7.5-36.6,16.7c0.6,7,1.4,13.7,1.9,20.5c18.7-11.7,40.4-20.5,60.2-20.5
 c9,0,26.5,1.7,26.5,14.6c0,19.5-28.4,32.1-50.5,32.1c-8.7,0-17.6-1.6-26-5.1L247.5,337.9z M231.9,293.3c-0.5-3.6-1-7.2-1.3-10.9
 c-5.3,3.5-10.6,6.7-15.3,9.5c-10.8,6.4-32.4,20-32.4,33c0,4,3,6.8,7.1,6.8C200,331.7,212.2,308.9,231.9,293.3z M235.4,321.6
 c-25.5,16.8-44.8,38.8-44.8,49.6c0,3.8,3.2,6.3,7.5,6.3c18.7,0,37.6-23.8,37.6-49.3C235.6,326,235.5,323.9,235.4,321.6z
  M233.6,278.9c18.1-12.6,36-29.9,36-50.5c0-5.1-1.9-13.2-8.6-13.2c-17.5,0-27.5,40.6-27.5,61.7V278.9z"/>
</g>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 93.4995 329.5063)" font-family="'Spinnaker-Regular'" font-size="114.694">S</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 328.4995 329.5063)" font-family="'Spinnaker-Regular'" font-size="114.694">J</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: The command you are using doesn't look like any ImageMagick commands I know? If you are using ImageMagick, have you tried `identify -list font` to see what fonts it knows about? Have you seen my post here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696433/why-font-list-is-empty-for-imagemagick/24701602#24701602

Comment: Added the type.xml file into the .magick directory. Used 'identify -list font' and all the fonts correctly appear in the list but when I use this command: /usr/local/bin/convert ~/desktop/example.svg ~/desktop/example.png, the same thing happens. Everything appears correctly except the font - it uses some basic sans serif font.