# Adding fonts to minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm using minimagick and want to add some text over images.  I need to know how to add additional fonts for minimagick to use.  For example, I am trying to use Chalkboard, which is an OSX font and I am getting the error 'unable to read font `chalkboard' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/898'.

Any help on how I can add in additional fonts.

Comment: Have a look at, and maybe vote for, my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696433/why-font-list-is-empty-for-imagemagick/24701602#24701602