# How can you use 'annotate' with 'montage' or pipe a for loop that uses 'convert', on a directory of images, to 'montage'?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, annotate, imagemagick-montage

I have been trying for days to write a script that creates a simple proof sheet from a directory of images. The only scripts I found `label` the images, which I don't like. I wanted to `annotate` them as per [Labeling on top of the Image itself...](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_on).

I was unable to use `annotate` rather than `label` with `montage` and could find no examples online. That would be ideal. If someone knows how to implement that, I would prefer it.

What I did so far is to first `resize` and `annotate` the images into a separate directory and then create the proof sheet using `montage`. That works but has the disadvantage of making lossy copies of lossy copies and requiring writing files to a directory.

I tried to pipe the output of the `convert` for loop to `montage` but didn't succeed. That would be the second best solution. If anyone knows how to do that, that would be very helpful.

This works but…:

```
d="<path to image directory>"
dirname=`basename "$d"`
echo $dirname
parent=`dirname "$d"`
echo $parent
parentdir=`basename "$parent"`
echo $parentdir
cd "$d"
if [ -f "$parentdir-$dirname proof sheet.jpg" ]
then
    rm "$parentdir-$dirname proof sheet.jpg"
fi
tilenum=5
spacing=1
scrw=$((1920-(tilenum*spacing+spacing)))
imgw=$(($scrw/$tilenum))
echo $imgw
if [ ! -d rszannot ]
then
    mkdir rszannot
else
    rm rszannot/*
fi
shopt -s nullglob # prevents errors for extensions not found
shopt -s nocaseglob # case insensitive args
for f in "${arg}"*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}
do
    fn=$(basename "${f%.*}")
    convert -verbose "$f" \
    -define jpeg:size=${imgw}x \
    -quality 100 \
    -resize ${imgw}x \
    -gravity south \
    -pointsize 20 \
    -stroke '#000C' -strokewidth 2 -annotate 0 '%f' \
    -stroke  none   -fill white    -annotate 0 '%f' \
    "rszannot/$fn-${imgw}x.jpg"
done
cd rszannot
montage -verbose \
-quality 100 \
-background black \
-geometry +${spacing}+${spacing} \
-tile ${tilenum}x \
*.jpg \
"../$parentdir-$dirname proof sheet.jpg"
open "../$parentdir-$dirname proof sheet.jpg"
shopt -u nocaseglob
shopt -u nullglob
```

[image: proof sheet]

Answer (score 1):

You can resize and annotate all your images in a sub shell and save to miff:, then pipe that to montage in Unix Imagemagick. Here is an example:

```
list="lena.jpg barn.jpg mandril3.jpg monet2.jpg zelda1.jpg redhat.jpg"
( 
for img in $list; do
echo >&2 "$img"
convert $img -resize "100x100^" -extent 100x100 \
-font helvetica -pointsize 14 -fill white \
-gravity south -annotate +0+5 "%f" \
miff:-
done
) | montage - -tile 3x2 -geometry +0+0 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. This worked. I was missing the parentheses around the for loop, `miff`:-, and the dash as argument to montage. Only 'problem' is I get `montage: improper image header /var/folders/_f/mth7tq5x4f3dpjkqs1z2y6mm0000gn/T/magick-13298qPmesOphcvrA' @ error/miff.c/ReadMIFFImage/1103.` I can't find an explanation online that fits this particular case.

Comment: From what I've been able to piece together, this error is due to a bug that flags the `miff` file as having a corrupt header. The `montage` command creates the proof sheet just the same so it is more of a warning than an error. I simply redirected stderr to 2>/dev/null to eliminate the message. I did a normalized difference image between the unpiped and the piped proof sheet images and the visible difference was negligible.

[differencenormpiped.png](https://postimg.cc/DW0tYWjW)

Comment: I still would like to know if you can just use `annotate` instead of `label` in `montage`.

Comment: No, -annotate cannot be used in place of label in montage. You can pipe between the two however as I did in my example.

Comment: Yes definitely. Thanks.

Comment: @hmj6jmh The parentheses around the `for` loop should not be necessary, they just create another (superfluous) process.

Comment: @hmj6jmhvYou can verify that by running the following and seeing that `wc` *"catches"* all 3 lines `for i in 1 2 3 ; do echo $i ; done | wc -l`

Comment: @Mark Setchell. The outer parentheses are needed to create a sub shell process so that one can use miff:- to collect all the images and send them to montage using stdin without having to save temp files.

Comment: @fmw42 Hi Fred. Mmmm... they shouldn't be necessary, see my comment above and here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30957183/2836621 I'll run some tests tomorrow - it's getting late.

Comment: @Mark. You are correct. It does indeed work. Interesting, since Anthony told me to use sub shell processing so that miff:- could be used in place of saving temp files. I never tried it without the sub shell. Perhaps I misunderstood something as I am not Unix expert.

Comment: Cool - you already have my vote!

Comment: @MarkSetchell. The command you had in your link works, but I am not able to get the command above to work without the subsoil. I sent you private email about that with examples and images.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help with my questions and your suggestion. I have posted an ADDITION in my answer showing that the command works fine without the sub shell processing.