# Unable to use installed font with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, osx-yosemite, freetype

I am using OS X 10.10.3 and installed ImageMagick using Homebrew.

I'm trying out ImageMagick to create a dynamic image generation script but I'm getting a font related error message.  This is the command I use, which is an example taken from ImageMagick's Font Effect page.  What can I do so that I can use the font installed on my machine with ImageMagick? The fonts are either TrueType or PostScript.

```
convert -size 320x100 xc:lightblue -font Arial -pointsize 72 \
-fill navy -annotate +25+65 'Anthony' \
-distort Arc 120  -trim +repage \
-bordercolor lightblue -border 10  /outputdirectory/font_arc.jpg
```

And this is the error message it returns.

```
convert: delegate library support not built-in `/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1560.
```

Below is the output when I run the command "convert -list configure"

```
Path: /opt/ImageMagick/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1//config-Q16/configure.xml

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CC             gcc
CFLAGS         -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -march=core2 -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
CODER_PATH     /opt/ImageMagick/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/modules-Q16/coders
CONFIGURE      ./configure  '--prefix' '/opt/ImageMagick' '--enable-delegate-build' '--enable-opencl' '--without-x' '--without-freetype' '--disable-static' 'CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.5'
CONFIGURE_PATH /opt/ImageMagick/etc/ImageMagick-6/
COPYRIGHT      Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS       -I/opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6
CXX            g++
CXXFLAGS       -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
DEFS           -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg fftw jng jpeg lcms lzma png ps tiff webp xml zlib
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS 'CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.5' --disable-deprecated --with-quantum-depth=16 --with-jemalloc=no --with-umem=no --with-autotrace=no --with-freetype=no --with-gslib=no --with-fontpath= --with-gvc=no --with-rsvg=no --with-wmf=no --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH /opt/ImageMagick/share/doc/ImageMagick-6
EXEC-PREFIX    /opt/ImageMagick
EXECUTABLE_PATH /opt/ImageMagick/bin
FEATURES       DPC OpenCL
FILTER_PATH    /opt/ImageMagick/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/modules-Q16/filters
HOST           x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
INCLUDE_PATH   /opt/ImageMagick/include/ImageMagick-6
LDFLAGS        -L/opt/ImageMagick/lib -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/fftw/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/fftw -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/jp2 -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/jpeg/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/jpeg -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/lcms/src/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/lcms/src -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/lzma/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/lzma -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/magick -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/png/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/png -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/tiff/libtiff/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/tiff/libtiff -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/wand -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/webp/.libs -L/Users/karlvr/Development/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0/webp -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib
LIB_VERSION    0x691
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER 6,9,1,0
LIBRARY_PATH   /opt/ImageMagick/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1
LIBS           -llcms -ltiff -ljpeg -lpng15 -lfftw3 -lwebp -L/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.1/lib -llzma -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -Wl,-framework,OpenCL -lm
NAME           ImageMagick
PCFLAGS        -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PREFIX         /opt/ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16
RELEASE_DATE   2015-03-22
SHARE_PATH     /opt/ImageMagick/share/ImageMagick-6
SHAREARCH_PATH /opt/ImageMagick/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/config-Q16
SVN_REVISION   18245
TARGET_CPU     x86_64
TARGET_OS      darwin14.1.0
TARGET_VENDOR  apple
VERSION        6.9.1
WEBSITE        http://www.imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

Name           Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FEATURES       
NAME           ImageMagick
QuantumDepth   16
```

And finally this is the result of "brew info imagemagick".

```
imagemagick: stable 6.9.1-3 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.imagemagick.org
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.1-3 (1444 files, 21M) *
Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: xz ✔, libtool ✔
Recommended: jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, freetype ✔
Optional: fontconfig ✔, libtiff ✔, little-cms ✘, little-cms2 ✔, libwmf ✘, librsvg ✘, liblqr ✘, openexr ✘, ghostscript ✔, webp ✘, fftw ✘, pango ✘
```

Adding to the above, here is a result from "identify -list format" for TrueType and PostScript fonts.

```
PFA* TTF       r--   Postscript Type 1 font (ASCII) (Freetype 2.5.5)
PFB* TTF       r--   Postscript Type 1 font (binary) (Freetype 2.5.5)    
TTC* TTF       r--   TrueType font collection (Freetype 2.5.5)
TTF* TTF       r--   TrueType font (Freetype 2.5.5)
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `identify -list font`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
identify -list font
```

to see what fonts you have available to you. If none, have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621).

Comment: Hi Mike,  Thanks for the suggestion.  I've already made my own type.xml and set it up just as you described in your post.

Whan I run "identify -list format" I get the following for TrueType
TTC* TTF       r--   TrueType font collection (Freetype 2.5.5)
TTF* TTF       r--   TrueType font (Freetype 2.5.5)

Are these something to do with it?

Comment: Can you click `edit` under your question and paste the extra info in there - it's really hard to read in the comments area.

Comment: I've edited my question and added an extra information in the bottom.  Sorry about that.