# Trouble with converting large pdf's

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

When using a command to convert a multi-page PDF into multiple .jpg's I get this error:

```
convert.exe: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c/ConnectPixelCacheServer/242.
convert.exe: CacheResourcesExhausted `C:/Users/tony/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-3204BqbQczbFuSJP101' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3702.
```

After 6 pages I get nothing but empty files. I am using this command: `for %f in (*.pdf) do convert -limit memory 6GiB -limit map 12GiB -limit disk 60gb -quality 100 -density 300x300 %f %~nf\%d.jpg`.
Also, My resource limits are:

```
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 17.051GP
  Memory: 7.9398GiB
  Map: 15.88GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 1536
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699200/6521116