# Imagemagick fonts not found in OSX

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew

When trying to add annotations to images in ImageMagick, It failed with the following message:

```
convert: unable to read font `(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype...
```

How do I make Imagemagick find these fonts?

Comment: It's already here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621

Comment: Cool! Wonder how I didn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was given by [Neville](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=20838) in [this post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20529):

1. Create an imagemagick configuration folder: `mkdir ~/.magick`
2. Save [this Perl script](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen) as `/tmp/script.pl`
3. Make the script executable: `chmod +x /tmp/script.pl`
4. Run the script locally and redirect the output to the file `type.xml` in `~/.magick`:  `/tmp/script.pl > ~/.magick/type.xml`

This solved the fonts problem, while [installing fondu](http://gothick.org.uk/2008/03/14/using-os-x-fonts-in-imagemagick/), the [imagemagick pkg](http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/) file and some other tricks didn't.

Great! Now I can annotate some [flickr cats](https://www.flickr.com/photos/n1ls/21133636976/in/explore-2015-09-05/) with the image size and resolution (I want this for finding the optimal resolution for an app I'm working on).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to get TTC fonts

Comment: On OSX 10 I found I had to edit the script to include /System/Library/Fonts as well as /Library/Fonts. Change the find on line 482 from `find /Library/Fonts -type f -name '*.*'` to `find /Library/Fonts /System/Library/Fonts -type f -name '*.*'`

Answer (score 5):

Adopting [Adam Matan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32421234/868724)'s answer, here's how I got this to work with imagemagick 7+ on macOS 10.12+ installed with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). (This also assumes you have `perl` installed.)

1. Download the [perl script](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen) and save it to `/usr/local/bin/imagick_type_gen`
2. Make the script executable:

   - `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/imagick_type_gen`
3. Find the font path for imagemagick by running `convert -list font | grep Path`. This should return where imagemagick is looking for fonts. The Apple path for me was this:

   - `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-22/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-apple.xml`
4. Run `imagick_type_gen` and direct the output to the path above:

   - `imagick_type_gen > /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-22/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-apple.xml`
5. Run `convert -list font | less` to see the font names imagemagick will use, e.g., some fonts will be labeled as `GeorgiaB` instead of `Georgia Bold`. (hit `q` to quit)

imagemagick should now see the fonts you have installed on the your system.

Comment: This seems to get system-installed fonts, but not the many that I have installed as a user. The script doesn't seem to take any parameters to fix this either. How hard is to also check ~/Library/Fonts ?

Comment: This worked for Homebrew; the accepted answer did not. Thanks.

Comment: @badkya I installed Ghostscript (brew install gs) and then it did output a list of fonts.

Comment: @Smek `brew install gs` did the job for me, you should post it as an answer ;)

Comment: Since Catalina, macOS fonts have moved so the script needs updating to look in `/System/Library/Fonts` - it occurs in two locations in the script (lines 478 and 482 at time of writing)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this issue is **copying the font** you need to a ~/ folder, or anywhere your script is, then give the direct path:

```
convert -font "~/MyFont.ttc"
```