# Using UTF text by ImageMagick

Tags: image, utf-8, imagemagick

I use `Ubuntu 14.0.4`. I want to use a file with UTF8 by a command of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). [Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode) you can see:

> If the UTF-8 text you wanting to draw has already been generated you
>   can read it directly from a file using '@filename'.For example here I
>   create a Chinese label from a UTF-8 encoded Chinese text file (without
>   a final newline in the file).

```
 convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 \
          -font ZenKaiUni label:@chinese_words.utf8   label_utf8.gif
```

Now I test a command that is look like above command for a text file with name `label1.txt` which it's content is a Persian word:

> سلام

Command is:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 label:@label1.txt   label_utf8.png
```

But I got this image:

[image]

You can see `?` characters instead of desired ones. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have omitted the `-font ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Which `font` I have to use?

Comment: One that can do Persian characters - sorry, I don't know any myself.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I try to use for example `KacstArt` as value of `-font` option, but I got this error:`convert.im6: unable to read font `KacstArt' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/853.`

Comment: Does your font file have an extension? Try adding that. Also, try `identify -list font | grep -i KacstArt` to see if that font is known to ImageMagick. If not, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell OK! I try your recommended command to test if the font is known for to ImageMagick and found that complete name of the font is `KacstArt-Medium`. Please add your comments as answer, so I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to specify the font for **ImageMagick** to use, so you want something like:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 -font XYZ ...
```

In order to make sure that your selected font is known to **ImageMagick**, you need to look in the list of known fonts:

```
identify -list font
```

or, more specifically in your case:

```
identify -list font | grep -i Kacst
```

If the font is listed, use that name. If not listed, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621).