# Installing additional fonts for Imagemagick on GAE Flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine, imagemagick

I'm using custom runtime on GAE Flexible environment.
Imagemagick is installed and it's working as expected.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install imagemagick -y
```

I now need additional fonts installed (as some pdfs, when being converted to images, aren't rendering correctly).

Are the steps to install a new font:

1. `apt-get install the font(s)`
2. Somehow get  imagick_type_gen  ( https://martin-thoma.com/add-a-new-font-to-imagemagick/)
3. Call `perl imagick_type_gen > types.xml`
4. Copy over imagemagick types with types generated in step 3.

Are the steps outlined correct?

How does one download a script that isn't available via apt-get (step 2)?

Does GAE flexible environment allow you to overwrite files (steps 3 and 4 above).

Thanks

Comment: This should help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621

Comment: You do not need to make Imagemagick know about the font names. You can call any font by its file path. Use -font path2/fontname.ttf, for example.