# How to use ImageMagick with Chinese fonts on Text to Image Handling

Tags: macos, fonts, imagemagick-convert

I try to use ImageMagick to handle a Chinese character to a image on my MacBook.

I use command to check the Chinese fonts available on my system.

`convert -list font | grep Font`

I did not get any.

Seen from the ImageMagick guide [Text to Image Handling](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/), Chinese font seems like supported , such as `ZenKaiUni`

And seen from the application Font Album of my MacBook. There are so many Chinese fonts.

I think it is OK. How to figure it out?

Comment: To get anything back from `convert -list font`, you must edit your type.xml file to include the fonts you want or use the perl script at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen to automatically load fonts from your font directory into the type.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in `ImagMagick` as [the font information it uses doesn't include language support](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/config/type-apple.xml.in), but it's easy with `Font Book.app` by creating a *Smart Collection* as follows:

[image]

On my Mac I have 35 fonts which include Chinese characters.

[image]

(The dimmed/greyed fonts are available but will need to be downloaded from Apple servers before I can use them, an automatic process done when selecting those fonts in any app.)

Answer (score 2):

You can either tell **ImageMagick** about all the fonts on your system, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621) and then they will show up if you do:

```
convert -list font
```

Then you can use shorthand:

```
convert -font Arial ...
```

---

Or, you can just tell **ImageMagick** the full path to any font on a per-invocation basis:

```
printf "Hello" | convert -pointsize 72 \
   -font "/Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/Frameworks/Flexo.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Fonts/Zingende Regular.ttf" \
   label:@- result.png
```

You would probably put Unicode for Chinese characters in place of my *"Hello"*.

[image]

Comment: Could you answer my another question: https://superuser.com/questions/1276446/how-to-use-imagemagick-on-chinese-text-to-image-handling

Answer (score 2):

I do not have any chinese fonts on my system, but here is an example of what I would suggest using the symbol font. First download a proper UTF-8 chinese font, i.e. one that supports UTF-8 characters. Then open a UTF-8 compatible text editor, choose that font and type your string. For example, here is a screensnap of the symbols.txt file that I created using the symbol font in my BBEdit UTF-8 compatible text editor on my Mac.

[image]

Then using ImageMagick,

```
convert -size 100x -font "/library/fonts/GreekMathSymbols Normal.ttf" label:@symbols.txt symbol.gif
```

And the resulting symbol.gif image is:

[image]

Adding .utf8 as suffix to your file is not adequate. You must create a text file in a UTF-8 compatible text editor using a UTF-8 compatible font.

Furthermore, most terminal windows do not support UTF-8 characters / fonts. So typing your characters directly into the command line in the terminal window does not always work. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode

Comment: You may not have any Chinese fonts (although macOS comes with at least one as standard) but you'll definitely have many fonts that support the Chinese character set.