# Annotating images with Image::Magick on mac installed with homebrew

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I've got ImageMagick software installed with homebrew on my mac and I'm using the Image::Magick Perl module. I'm trying to figure out how to annotate images with some text. Nothing I've tried works:

```
$error = $image->Annotate(font => 'Courier', gravity => 'North', pointsize=>100, fill=>'black', text => 'blah blah');

$error = $image->Annotate(font => '/Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf', gravity => 'North', pointsize=>100, fill=>'black', text => 'blah blah');
```

I'm figuring it can't find the font but maybe something else is wrong. No error is thrown. I have installed ghostscript with homebrew but that didn't help.

Partial output from identify -list font

```
  Font: Times-BoldItalic
    family: Times
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n021024l.pfb
  Font: Times-Italic
    family: Times
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n021023l.pfb
  Font: Times-Roman
    family: Times
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/n021003l.pfb
```

Comment: See what fonts are installed in Terminal with `identify -list font`. If you have none, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621

Comment: If you have only Times then it's not going to work if you choose Courier or Impact.

Comment: Maybe try this in Terminal and see how `z.png` looks... `convert -size 100x100 xc:white -gravity center -fill red -font /Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf -annotate 0 "Hi there" z.png`

Comment: @Borodin It should work if OP specifies full path to `/Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf` like he suggests he did, even if that font is not configured into ImageMagick's configuration settings.

Comment: @Borodin I have hundreds of fonts. that's just a snippet I posted.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yup, that worked. hmmm.

Comment: Maybe you are writing black on black? Or the Northern gravity is throwing you off the top of the page?

Comment: Nope. Black on mostly white. I tried with an without gravity. Maybe I can just have my perl script run a command line command for the existing image instead. How would that command look? ImageMagick commands confuse the hell out of me.

Comment: Try setting Gravity to `center`, as it defaults to NorthWest even if you don't set it.

Comment: Bam! Yup, there it is.

Comment: It's weird though, it's not always centered. For some images it is actually appearing near the top, sometimes in the center. It depends on the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Setting it to North or NorthWest makes the top of the image the **bottom** reference point for the text, i.e. the baseline of the text.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So I just need to lower it. I can figure that out. Thanks so much! Saved me probably 2 hours!

Comment: Try running `identify YourImage.png` in the Terminal, and see if there is any +nnn+nnn after the image dimensions which would mean the image has been cut from a larger one and has remembered its original position. To ignore it, repage your image before use... `convert YourImage.png +repage ... -annotate ...`

Comment: Yup, that appears to be the case. Beautiful. I would have never figured that out.

Comment: docs for Image::Magick don't mention anything about a "repage" option, however.

Comment: I think you can use `$img->Set( page=>'0x0+0+0' );`

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are the Magick Man! That did it. You have now saved me probably 6 hours. I owe you many beers.

Comment: OK, so now I can do NorthEast for gravity and not have to make any adjustments. It just places the text in the upper right hand corner, no muss, no fuss. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, I may write it up later (after France vs Peru World Cup football match) as an answer that you could maybe accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have trouble finding your textual output with **ImageMagick**, try the following suggestions:

**Suggestion 1**

Use contrasting fill and stroke so you can be reasonably sure of seeing your text on any background:

```
magick ... -fill cyan -stroke magenta ...
```

**Suggestion 2**

Set gravity to `center` in case you are writing beyond the edges of your image:

```
magick ... -gravity center ...
```

**Suggestion 3**

Specify the **full path** to a font file so ImageMagick will find it even if it is not configured into its configuration files:

```
magick ... -font /Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf ...
```

**Suggestion 4**

Repage your image after loading so it forgets any old page settings it may have had when it was maybe previously part of some larger image and was cropped:

```
magick ... +repage ...
```

So, in summary, try a command like:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:white -gravity center -fill cyan -stroke magenta -font /Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf -annotate 0 "Hi there" result.png
```

[image]